# Change single caliper to dual

Tags: brakes, gmc, caliper

I currently have single calipers on the rear axle.  Am I able to replace these with dual calipers on each side of the rear axle or will there be issues?

Comment: Truck is an 02 gmc C7500 diesel

Comment: Please do not type in ALL CAPITALS. It's perceived as SHOUTING, and is impolite.

Comment: Is this an [X - Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info)? Why do you want to have dual calipers on the rear axle?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you looking to actually have two calipers per axle, or are you looking to upgrade your current calipers (ie: single piston calipers to dual piston calipers)?

Comment: Parts lookup shows that 2 piston calipers and 4 piston are both options for topkick c7500. You would need to determine if the master cylinder or other components are different for those models.